# Class inheritance or nested class, which is better?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I've a problem, i've those class, that now works, because i've the attribute in public, but if i put it in private, or protected and inherited to the second class, it not work, how can i do it?

```
template <typename T>
class BinaryNode
{
public:
    T key;
    BinaryNode<T>* left;
    BinaryNode<T>* right;
    BinaryNode<T>* parent;
    BinaryNode(){}
    ~BinaryNode(){}
};
```

And this:

```
template <typename T>
class BinarySearchTree
{
private:
    BinaryNode<T>* root;
    BinaryNode<T>* newNode(T key);

    BinaryNode<T>* minimum(BinaryNode<T>* node);
    BinaryNode<T>* maximum(BinaryNode<T>* node);
    BinaryNode<T>* successor(BinaryNode<T>* node);

    void insert(BinaryNode<T>** node, T key);
    BinaryNode<T>* search(BinaryNode<T>* node, T key);
    void distance(BinaryNode<T>* node, T key);
    void inorderTreeWalk(BinaryNode<T>* node);
public:
    BinarySearchTree();
    ~BinarySearchTree();

    void insert(T key);
    BinaryNode<T>* search(T key);
    void distance(T key);
    void inorderTreeWalk();

    BinaryNode<T>* remove(BinaryNode<T>* node);
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. But perhaps `BinaryNode` should be a `friend` of `BinarySearchTree`? Or you need to have `public` accessors to your `private`/`protected` data in `BinaryNode`. Otherwise how did you expect `BinarySearchTree` to access the properties?

Comment: There is no universal solutions. Please, add info about [What have you tried so far](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/), how exactly "it not work" *for you*, and provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (not copy-paste of whole codebase). Without that information we barely can help you.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/s8xsn3q01ysyy4f/classi.h This is the header file with all, how can i do all attributes of BinaryNode in private, or nested class in binarysearchtree?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the node is closely coupled to the tree:

You might make the tree a friend of node or use a nested class:

```
class Node {
    private:
    friend class Tree;
    ...
};

class Tree {
    ...
};
```

or

```
class Tree {
    private: // maybe protected
    class Node {
        public:
        ...
    };
};
```

Comment: dropbox.com/s/s8xsn3q01ysyy4f/classi.h This is the header file with all, how can i do all attributes of BinaryNode in private, or nested class in binarysearchtree?

Answer (score 0):

You could make accessible "getter" functions to the nodes so you can traverse down the tree in your binary search tree.

```
template <typename T>
class BinaryNode
{
private:
    T key;
    BinaryNode<T>* left;
    BinaryNode<T>* right;
    BinaryNode<T>* parent;
public:
    BinaryNode(){}
    ~BinaryNode(){}

    T const& getKey() const { return key; }
    const BinaryNode<T>* getLeft() const { return left; }
    const BinaryNode<T>* getRight() const { return right; }
    const BinaryNode<T>* getParent() const { return parent; }
};
```

Now `BinarySearchTree<T>` can traverse through the tree to do the search without having direct access to the members or being able to modify them.

OF course you will probably want some methods too to modify the value (set functions)